# Targeting specific elements of cell arrays (Matlab)

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, cell-array

I currently have a cell array consisting of 7x1 vectors. I need to extract the first element (1,1) of each vector from each cell and store these values in a new array. This is what I currently have:

```
for j = 1:numel(xvalues)
    cellj = xvalues{j};
    a = cellj(1:1);
    avalues(1:j) = a;
end
```

However, I am just generating a cell array with the first element of the last cell, repeating. 
How can I fix this?

Comment: That `1:j` in your code should be just `j`.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use *cellfun* to apply a function to each element in a cell array. So to extract the first element of each vector the following should work.

```
avalues = cellfun(@(x) x(1),xvalues);
```

Cellfun loops through each element in the cell array and passes it in to the anonymous function via @(x). We then process x by taking the first element x(1).

Answer (score 1):

In cases such as yours, where the cell contents are matrices of the same size, and assuming your inputs are small enough (meaning that neither memory nor runtime are imminent issues) you can convert the cell array into a numeric matrix and select a vector along the relevant dimension:

```
function out = q48740494
%% Generate some data:
c = squeeze(num2cell(randi(20,7,1,20),[1,2]));
% c = 20×1 cell array of {7x1 double}
%% Convert this into a numeric array and output:
out = cell2mat(c.'); out = out(1,:);
% BONUS: another version of the line above.
% out = subsref(cell2mat(c.'), substruct('()', {1,1:numel(c)}) ) ;
```